# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : adding identity failing

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm using VS 2022, ASP.NET Core 6 MVC and Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (v15).

Git project: [https://github.com/Wizmi24/MVC_BookStore]

I'm trying to add --> new scaffolded item --> identity.

Default layout page, override all files and mine Data context
when I click add, I get this error:

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
> 'Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'MyProjectName'

I cleared NuGet Package cache as I saw it may help, but all it do is just prolong and this same error is visible after trying to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`, which is installed. I checked the packages and made sure they are the same version (6.0.11).

Comment: There is no SQL Server **18** version - they are numbered by year - 2012 (v11), 2014 (v12), 2016 (v13), 2017 (v14), 2019 (v15) and the newest is 2022 (v16) - there's no v18 anywhere to be seen. So what are you **really** using? Run `SELECT @@VERSION` on it if you're not sure ...

Comment: sql server management studio v18.12 version 15.0.18420.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cloned your project to test, and the problem you mentioned did appear. Not sure why, but I finally got it working by updating the NuGet package:

I updated the two packages `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` to version 7.0.1 (you need to pay attention to the sequence when updating), then add scaffolded Identity, and I succeeded.

You can try my method, if the Identity is successfully added, but the following exception is encountered at runtime:

[image]

You need to add `builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyBookContext>();` before

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyBookContext>();
```

`MyBookContext` is the `Data context class` selected when you add Identity:

[image]

In addition, if there is a 404 error in your area routing, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to modify it.

Hope this can help you.

**Edit1:**

I think it might be a problem caused by naming duplication. Please try to change the name of the context generated by Identity.

As you can see, the `ApplicationDbContext` generated by Identity is consistent with the `ApplicationDbContext` namespace in your `MyBook.DataAccess`:

[image]

So naming the same will cause conflict:

[image]

So you need to change the naming to avoid conflicts. For example:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
    ));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContextIdentity>();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContextIdentity>();
```

**Edit2:**

As I mentioned in the original answer, if you get a 404 error, you can try to refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to fix the area routing.

The easiest way is to directly change the routing settings in `Program.cs`:

```
app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
   name: "Customer",
   areaName: "Customer",
   pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Then add the `Area` property to the controller:

```
[Area("Customer")]
public class HomeController : Controller{}
```

There seems to be a problem with your `Repository.cs`, so I changed the `Index` to only output a string to test the result.

```
public string Index()
{
    return "success";
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

If your `Repository.cs` also has problems when you test it, you can make a new post for everyone to help you fix this problem(Because this question strays so far from your original question, one post is better off addressing only one question).

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to generate identity, but as you said i run into system.aggregateException, but your solution on this didn't work, probably because my data context name is ApplicationDbContext (in class library MyBook.DataAccess/Data) which is the same as generated (in class library MyBook/Areas/Identity/Data), any ideas for this problem?

Comment: Hi @Wizmi, this is a conflict caused by duplication of naming, I updated my answer, please check.

Comment: Hi @Wizmi, have you tried it? Is it effective?

Comment: I tried but now i get the error
'This page was not found on localhost 
The website at https://localhost:44353/ was not found
HTTP ERROR 404'

Comment: Hi @Wizmi, I updated my answer again to solve your routing issue, if my answer helped you, could you please accept it as the answer?

Comment: I added area names to the controllers and updated Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer to 7.0.1 and it's WORKING!!!! Thank you very much for your time and patience